# Finding which contigs go into any given scaffold in an 454-Newbler assembly

Tags: scaffold

I guess there should be a quite simple script for calling which contigs go into which scaffolds. This is 454 data assembled with Newbler.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the corrections ;)

A simple 'grep' on the 454Scaffolds.txt file gives me the folloving output.

-bash-3.2$ grep scaffold10511 454Scaffolds.txt
scaffold10511   1   1251    1   W   contig368342    1   1251    +
scaffold10511   1252    2340    2   N   1089    fragment    yes
scaffold10511   2341    3244    3   W   contig368343    1   904 +
scaffold10511   3245    5704    4   N   2460    fragment    yes
scaffold10511   5705    6500    5   W   contig368344    1   796 +
scaffold10511   6501    7472    6   N   972 fragment    yes
scaffold10511   7473    10932   7   W   contig368345    1   3460    +
scaffold10511   10933   11579   8   N   647 fragment    yes
scaffold10511   11580   15817   9   W   contig368346    1   4238    +
scaffold10511   15818   19635   10  N   3818    fragment    yes
scaffold10511   19636   21767   11  W   contig368347    1   2132    +
scaffold10511   21768   22244   12  N   477 fragment    yes
scaffold10511   22245   25733   13  W   contig368348    1   3489    +
scaffold10511   25734   28642   14  N   2909    fragment    yes
scaffold10511   28643   32182   15  W   contig368349    1   3540    +

As I understands it then this scaffold is based on contig368342-->368349, so that should answer this question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can also use grep -f :)